# User file upload: Check if file exists before upload (prompt overwrite yes/no)

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I have a simple form that allows users to choose a file then upload it.
How can I check if the file exists before the file is uploaded, if it exists, prompt the user to confirm the overwrite (yes - overwrite, no - don't do anything/cancel). I have heard it's best to use ajax, but I have little experience with ajax and can't find an example to implement.

Form code:

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='<?php $_server['PHP_SELF']; ?>'>
      <input type='file' name='file_upload'>          
      <br><br>
      <input type='submit' name='submit' value="Upload">
      </form>
```

My attempt:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if(file_exists($fullFileName)){ 
    echo '<script>
         if (!confirm("Do you want to overwrite the existing file?")) {
           window.location.replace(window.location.href);
         }
         </script>';
         unlink($fullFileName);
         if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], '' . $_FILES['file_upload']['name'])){
           die('Errrrrr! Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.');
         }
  }
    else {
      if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], '' . $_FILES['file_upload']['name'])){
              die('Errrrrr! Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.');
      }
    }
}
```

My code overwrites the file even if 'Cancel' is selected at the confirm. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of posting back, you should attach an event listener to the fileupload button so when a file is selected you do a basic Ajax call to your script that checks if the file is valid and can return true or false or anything. Then depending on the value you can either leave it alone or alert the user that the file already exists and clear the fileupload input so they have to try again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your approach

Firstly it makes sense that the file is always over written. You're calling `move_uploaded_file` even if the file exists. In order to do this using ajax you must first make a call to the server and call `file_exists($fullFileName)`. If the file exists return true, otherwise return false. Based on this result you can either proceed to upload the file if the file does not exist, or if it does exist prompt the user about whether they would like to overwrite the file. JQuery has a great [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) system which will make things a lot easier for you.

Example(NOTE - This is not tested code - It is simply to give you an idea of how to solve the problem):

```
$("#formButton").submit(function(event){
    // Prevent form submission until we can call the server
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("does_file_exist.php",
    {
        file:filename
    },
    function(data, status){
        var submit = true;
        if(data=="true"){
             if(!window.confirm('Overwrite File'){
                 submit = false;
             }
        }
        if(submit){
            // Enable default form behaviour and submit
            $("#formButton").unbind("submit");
            $("#formButton").submit();
        }
    });
}
```